# Ember.js - bind events in the controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, dom-events

I've just started with Ember.js and the thing I still don't understand why events are bound inside the view, like this:

```
App.ClickableView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt) {
     alert("ClickableView was clicked!");
  }
});
```

In JavaScriptMVC and Sencha Touch things like this are handled in the controller. How can, for example, multiple controllers bind to the same event?

Comment: in your handlebars template you can use the action helper... something like this `{{action handlerName this on='click' target='controller'}}` but you'd ideally want to rename the `handlerName` to something more appropriate. If it's a button or link you don't need to specify `on='click'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default context for events has changed to the router (a controller) from the view in the latest versions of ember. The event will be handled by the current router (state), like this:

```
root : Ember.Route.extend({
    index : Ember.Route.extend({
        route : '/',
        connectOutlets : function(router) {
            var ac = router.get('applicationController');
            ac.connectOutlet({
                name : 'topnav',
                outletName : 'topnav'
            });
        },
        click: function(event, context) {
           alert("ClickableView was clicked!");
        }
})
```

If you had other click events in other states, the app would not be confused because it knows which state/route it is in.

You can handle your events in the view or controller, but it is recommended to handle them in the router.

Comment: I guess you need to bind something to that 'click' function/action. How is that done ?

Comment: For browser events, it is done automatically. A click event is raised if the user clicks on a button, and it is then passed to the router for handling. You can also define custom events in your markup like this: {{ action custom }}